# How to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}-q^{2}+\frac{2}{3}q^{3}}}\mathrm dq$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

My calculus skills are too weak to solve this integral:
$$\int_\limits{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}-q^{2}+\frac{2}{3}q^{3}}}\mathrm dq$$
I haven't found the right substitution yet (and don't just want to accept Wolfram Alpha's answer).

Comment: I'd be surprised if that question has a calculus answer (that is, a substitution that leads to a recognizable antiderivative). What's the source of the question? What course is it homework for?

Comment: Something doesn't look right, the integrand becomes imaginary for sufficiently negative $q$...

Comment: I wanted to give the hint that $q=1$ is a zero of the cubic polynomial. Then, I noticed it is actually a double zero of the cubic polynomial and hence, the integral explodes around $q=1$.

Answer (score 2):

You can start like this:

First of all we can factor out $\sqrt{3}$ to obtain:

$\sqrt{3}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{-2x^3-3x^2+1}}\, dx$

Now observe $-2x^3-3x^2+1=0$. We see pretty easily, that x=-1 is a root. Hence (maybe after a long division) we get:

$(x+1)(-2x^2-x+1)=-2x^3-3x^2+1$

And furthermore we get $-2x^2-x+1=(x+1)(-2x+1)$

Hence: $\sqrt{3}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2(1-2x)}}\, dx=\sqrt{3}\int \frac{1}{(x+1)\sqrt{1-2x}}\, dx$

Now substitute $u=\sqrt{1-2x}$.

Comment: I just noticed, that I swaped a sign here. As others have pointed out, are you sure, that you made no mistake?

Comment: @kNiEsSoKk No, I calculated with $-2x^3$ instead of $2x^3$. But the good news are, that it should be similar to my calculation, and it should be possible.

Comment: Possible to integrate at least.